# xcode 4, Thread 1:Program received signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS."

Tags: xcode4

When i added the code(textField.text=preTotalNumber;) in the method(onButtonPressed),the failure appeared.
Can anyone please help me?thk

Answer (score 0):

preTotalNumber should be an NSString, and if not you should convert it to NSString. for instance if it's an integer you can use the following:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", preTotalNumber];
```

Comment: You can use (NSZombieEnabled = YES). This parameter is great during developing time it helps very much in placing the exact location for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. You can use it by adding a new parameter to the executable file of your application.